# Need interactive shell script setup in jenkins

Tags: shell, jenkins

I Have a deployment script which at run time asks for confirmation to proceed further for deployment and password. I have used publish-over-ssh plugin with jenkins to run my build and deployment script on target server.
But As deployment Shell script is Interactive it takes user inputs at run time and in jenkins the build is going in hang status.
Is there any way I can setup jenkins configuration for depolyment script to run on target unix server and at run time jenkins should prompt me for user confirmation and password.
Please suggest.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins doesn't support interactive scripts. Just pass the confirmation on standard input, for example:

```
yes | ./my_script.sh
```

For user names and passwords it's better (security and complexity-wise) to use the [SSH Agent Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/SSH+Agent+Plugin).

Making such a script interactive is anyway not the *nix way. If possible I would highly recommend changing it to take all the parameters it needs to run without any interaction. Then you can simply do this:

```
./my_script.sh --option-name=option-value [...] parameter-value [...]
```

Comment: But it asks for the password of the tool on which we load the build. I am trying this configuration in publish-over-ssh plugin

Comment: Now resolved the issue of user confirmation but still the job is hanging because of required password at shell script run time. Thank you so much.

Comment: You need to change your deployment script. Jenkins is not interactive. It will not ever prompt you for anything.

Comment: People thinking to use mask passworrd plugin will it be helpfull?

Comment: You can use that to hide the password at least in the shell output page, but in that case you probably want to lock down your security properly - I would be surprised if privileged users couldn't get at the password in some Jenkins page (or using the API to get the job parameters).

Comment: @user1587356 I can't give you a fully working solution. Please learn how to use Jenkins and any plugins you need, and ask specific questions here only when the documentation doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Commented the interactions which were not necessary and for Password prompt set Public Key authentication through key gen process.